# Eliminar filas de un dataframe cuyos valores empiecen por unos determinados caracteres en Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con una columna de título 'Evento'. En esa columna, cuando aparezcan valores que empiecen por las letras UE (son códigos alfanuméricos) quiero eliminar esa fila en su totalidad en el dataframe

Gracias!

Comment: He probado y me sale un dataframe vacío, solo con los encabezados

Answer (score 0):

La columna "Evento" contiene cadenas. Eso te permite hacer algunas operaciones "vectoriales" de cadenas sobre esa columna, si usas `df.Evento.str`.

Por ejemplo, una función que puedes aplicar es `.startswith()` como en:

```py
df.Evento.str.startswith("UE")
```

Eso produce como resultado una columna de booleanos que será `True` para las filas cuyo Evento comience por "UE" y `False` para las que no. Esta columna de booleanos podemos usarla entre corchetes para seleccionar sólo las filas para las que la condición sea `True`, así:

```py
df[df.Evento.str.startswith("UE")]
```

Eso mostrará solo las filas cuyo evento comience por "UE". Lo que quieres es lo contrario asi que podemos aplicar el operador `~` a la expresión dentro de los corchetes. El resultado serán las filas que **no** comiencen por "UE". Ese resultado podemos asignarlo de nuevo a `df`:

```py
df = df[~df.Evento.str.startswith("UE")]
```

De este modo es como si hubieras eliminado las filas que comienzan por UE.

### Demo

Considera el siguiente dataframe:

```html
   Evento  Valor
0     EUA     88
1     UAE     85
2     EUA     52
3     UEA     12
4     UEA     10
5     UEA    100
6     AUE     83
7     AUE     90
8     AEU     92
9     EAU     74
10    UAE     33
11    AUE     60
12    AEU     69
13    AUE     98
14    UAE     86
15    EAU     31
16    UEA     21
17    AUE     13
18    UAE     20
19    AUE     33
```

Por si alguien quiere replicar el ejemplo, lo he generado aleatoriamente con el siguiente código:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Evento": ["".join(random.sample("AUE", 3)) for _ in range(20)],
    "Valor":  [random.randint(10, 100) for _ in range(20)]
})
```

Vemos que las filas 3, 4, 5 y 16 tienen Evento que comienza por "UE". Aplicando la expresión antes explicada:

```py
df = df[~df.Evento.str.startswith("UE")]
```

El resultado ya no tiene esas filas:

```html
   Evento  Valor
0     EUA     88
1     UAE     85
2     EUA     52
6     AUE     83
7     AUE     90
8     AEU     92
9     EAU     74
10    UAE     33
11    AUE     60
12    AEU     69
13    AUE     98
14    UAE     86
15    EAU     31
17    AUE     13
18    UAE     20
19    AUE     33
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ahora me funciona. Copio el código con el último detalle que le he  ya que no dije que en el dataframe había datos nulos NaN y no funcionaba sin esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Perdon, corregido el código anterior.                                                                           df = df[~df.Evento.str.startswith("UE", na = False)]